# Is there a way to pass function from objective-c++ to standard c++?

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

I want to pass objective-c++ function pointer to standard c++ so that I can call objective-c method on C++.

Here is what I want to achieve:

```
//C++ side
class CppSide
{
public:
    void(*TestFunction)();
};

//objective-c++ side
@interface InteropController : GLKViewController{
}
-(void) PickFile; //I want to pass PickFile address to TestFunction
@end
```

Following is what I did, but doesn't work

```
InteropController* controller = [[InteropController alloc] init];
CppSide* cppSide = new CppSide();
cppSide->TestFunction = [controller methodForSelector:@selector(PickFile:)];
cppSide->TestFunction(); //EXC_BADccess(code=1, address=0x2d)
```

How should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lazy, easy way is to pass an std::function that calls the objC code (eg, with a lambda).

However, what you have there is a raw C function pointer.  You will need to write a C function (or use a non-capturing lambda):

```
cppSide->TestFunction = [](){ ...  ObjC Code here ...};
```

However, you have no way of referring to the parent scope there - only to the global scope.

If you can change that instead to use an std::function, you will have much more flexibility:

```
cppSide->TestFunction = [=](){[controller PickFile: ... ];};
```

If you can't, for some reason, change that function pointer type, consider changing it so that it at the very least expects a data pointer:

```
class CppSide
{
public:
    void(*TestFunction)(void *data);
};
```

And then you can do:

```
cppSide->TestFunction = [](void *data) {
    InteropController* controller = static_cast<InteropController*>(data);
    [controller PickFile: ... ];
}
```

The caller that invokes the function pointer then needs to explicitly pass a controller.

Comment: Thank you!! This is great. And I found that what I did is right after delete ':' on selector

Comment: I recommend enabling the C++14 standard, the lambda's are much nicer (including generic lambda's, with type inference)